# Comparision asymptotic notation

Tags: notation, asymptotics, computer-science

I can get the result of an asymptotic two expressions by using limit or definitions of Big-Oh. However, I cannot express the following one in terms of $n$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^k$$

I want to compare it with $n^{k+1}$.

Comment: Maybe you mean $n^{k+1}$?

Comment: @gimusi, yes exactly. It's been fixed.

Comment: the you can refer to the given hint

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall that by [**Faulhaber's formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{k} = \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}+O(n^k)$$